# Python: Fastest way to make dict from list of dicts

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Queryset with annotations gave me result list like this:

```
[{'completed__sum': 1, 'offer__count': 2, 'offer': 1}, {'completed__sum': 0, 'offer__count': 1, 'offer': 2}]
```

I want to get something like that:

```
{1:{'completed__sum': 1, 'offer__count': 2},2:{'completed__sum': 0, 'offer__count': 1}}
```

where keys `1` and `2` are values of `'offer': X` field.

What is the fastest way to convert result of query to needed form? Or is there any way to receive result of queryset in that format?

---

Here is my QuerySet:

```
Progress.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).values('offer').annotate(Count('offer')).annotate(Sum('completed'))
```

My model:

```
class Progress(models.Model):  
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=User)  
    offer = models.ForeignKey(to=Offer)  
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: this question has nothing to do with django, and everything to do with  python builtins.

Comment: I used Django tag for case if there is another way to format result of Django's annotated queryset's output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

works on python 2.6 +

use the [dict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) constructor with enumerate.

```
list_of_dicts = [
    {'completed__sum': 1, 'offer__count': 2, 'offer': 1},
    {'completed__sum': 0, 'offer__count': 1, 'offer': 2}]

dictionary = dict((d['offer'], dict((k, v) for k, v in d.items() if k != 'offer')) for d in list_of_dicts)

print dictionary
>>> 
{1: {'completed__sum': 1, 'offer__count': 2}, 2: {'completed__sum': 0, 'offer__count': 1}}
```

**edit:** just found a much better way to do this. if you arent using the list anymore and are going to keep only the final results.

```
dictionary = dict((d.pop('offer'), d) for d in list_of_dicts)
```

Comment: "where keys `1` and `2` are values of `'offer': X` field"

Comment: Yep, that looks faster. `1000 loops, best of 3: 1 msec per loop`. Looks like exactly what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> {x['offer']: dict(y for y in x.iteritems() if y[0] != 'offer') for x in [{'completed__sum': 1, 'offer__count': 2, 'offer': 1}, {'completed__sum': 0, 'offer__count': 1, 'offer': 2}]}
{1: {'completed__sum': 1, 'offer__count': 2}, 2: {'completed__sum': 0, 'offer__count': 1}}
```

Comment: On my computer that variant worked faster than others:    `python -m timeit "{x['offer']: dict(y for y in x.iteritems() if y[0] != 'offer') for x in [dict(offer=x,completed__sum=1,offer__count=1) for x in xrange(1000)]}"  
100 loops, best of 3: 3.13 msec per loop`